# Using R's purrr::map with polite to scrape multiple pages returns only one of the pages

Tags: r, purrr, rvest

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages from onebite.app/reviews/fans using the following code:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(polite)
library(purrr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'purrr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:magrittr':
#> 
#>     set_names

obr_polite_pg <- paste0("https://onebite.app/reviews/fans?page=", seq(1:3), "&minScore=0&maxScore=10")

session <- bow("https://www.onebite.app/reviews/fans", force = TRUE, user_agent = "matthewramsdell@icloud.com")

obr_responses <- map(obr_polite_pg, ~scrape(session, query = list(i = .x)))

obr_rctitle <- map(obr_responses, ~html_elements(.x, ".reviewCard__title") %>% 
                                 html_text())
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

First I created a vector of 3 sequential webpages, and then tried to map the polite and rvest code over it, but instead of scraping all three pages, it only scraped the first page, but did it three times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `https://api.onebite.app/review?userType=REGULAR&limit=30&offset=30&minScore=0&maxScore=10` data actually coming from API call

Comment: excellent. thank you. how did you know it was from an api?

Comment: I pressed the next button and watched the network traffic in dev tools (Chrome. Network tab F12). Filtered on XHR